# Kotlin - "android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity" on an Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, adapter

I'm trying to call an intent when select an item of a bottomNavigationView:

```
 R.id.nova_foto_barra_cartao -> {
      val intent = CameraView.buildIntent(context.applicationContext, Constants.ULCERS)
      (context as Activity).startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
 }
```

The code is written inside of an Adapter:

```
class CartaoTipologiaAdapter(private val cartoesTipologia: List<CartaoTipologia>, private val context: Context) : Adapter<CartaoTipologiaAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

Comment: Please show the code from where context is created. Looks like you pass the reference of Application, not the activity.

Comment: If you need an `Activity` then just pass an `Activity` argument, downcasting Context to Activity is a code smell

Comment: if the context is an activity use just context instead of context.getApplicationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely passing an application context into the adapter, which you then cast to an Activity. So having a crash here is the expected behavior.

It's safer to provide a custom callback from your adapter to the place where it is used. This lets you create the adapter without hard wiring its behavior to the activity. Then your callback implementation can take care of the action to perform.

Answer (score 0):

In code where you create an instance of `CartaoTipologiaAdapter` make sure you pass `Activity` as the `context`, not `context.applicationContext`. If you create the instance of `CartaoTipologiaAdapter` in activity, pass activity as `context`:

```
val adapter = CartaoTipologiaAdapter(yourList, this@YourActivity)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass [your current Activity].this